# How to create implicit generic bindings with Guice?

Tags: java, generics, binding, guice, implicit

Here is my problem, I have a `Client` interface that has got a `<T> Prop<T> getProp(Class<T>)` method. A `PropKey` may be constructed with `PropKey.of(Class)`.

I inject an instance of `Client` in a module like this `bind(Client.class).to(ClientImpl.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);` and I wanna be able to inject `Prop` like this :

```
public class MyService implements Service {
    @Inject Client client;
    @Inject Prop<User> user;
}
```

How can I tell Guice that injection of `Prop<User>` will lead to `client.getProp(User.class)`. I primarily searched how to do this via SPI but I didn't find any way to get unknown binding. I also reviewed Jukito which is known to be a quality project using SPI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to get Guice to bind `Prop<T>` for all types `T` unless `Prop` is an injectable concrete class itself.  In that case it will "just work."

But if the set of types `T` is small you can bind to providers explicitly like this:

```
class PropProvider<T> implements Provider<Prop<T>> {
    private final Class<T> type;
    @Inject Client client;

    PropProvider(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public void get() {
        return client.getProp(type);
    }
}

class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(new TypeLiteral<Prop<User>>() { })
                .toProvider(new PropProvider(User.class));
        // More similar statments...
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can use [custom injections](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CustomInjections) to be able to write something like

```
class MyService implements Service {
    @Inject Client client;
    @InjectProp Prop<User> user;
}
```

but you'll need to use a custom annotation.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I'm actually already doing that. I wish there would be a way to use a single `@Inject` annotation.